# How to fine out if there is an empty space from certain position to a certain position in a string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a sequence like `'111111111111111        '`

How can I find out if there is a blank space in 15 - 23 position in sql?

Comment: What do you want the query to return?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 WHERE SUBSTRING ( '111111111111111        ',15, 8) Like '% %'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 16. Afaik the offset is 1 for the index.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether the 15th character is to be included or not. Is if it was zero based, it'd be 14/15 depending on inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

using `charindex()`

```
declare @str char(23) = '111111111111111        '
select charindex(' ',@str,15)
```

returns: `16`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QJGCZ57112